# How is DOM and Virtual DOM represented in memory?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, virtual-dom

What's the difference, why is it faster to access Virtual DOM than just DOM?

Comment: read the following link [click here](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/10/the-difference-between-virtual-dom-and-dom/)

Comment: Quoting from @salmankhan's link: *The Virtual DOM is an abstraction of the HTML DOM. It is lightweight and detached from the browser-specific implementation details.*

Comment: This might be helpful as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965738/what-is-virtual-dom

Comment: I am talking in context of their memory representation

Comment: Both are a mix of fixed-layout structs and hashtables. The difference is that virtual dom usually has to carry less internal information than real dom nodes. But the precise memory layouts are implementation-dependent in either case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the difference

The *virtual DOM* is **any in-memory representation of the real DOM elements**.

It is an abstraction over the *real HTML DOM* and the **level of abstraction varies based on how much details you want to keep** in *virtual DOM*.

Usually, first the changes are made to in-memory objects before rendering the same to via *real HTML DOM* page.

> why is it faster to access Virtual DOM than just DOM?

*Virtual DOM* is **already in memory**, on the other hand *real DOM* has to be accessed from page and loaded to memory for any operation.

**Simple Example**

Lets say you want to *render a simple list of items*, and only following properties of each list item is of concern to you

- Background-color
- Display value
- Font size and color
- Alignment (left, center or right aligned)

Since only these properties matter to your feature, you need a data structure to store these

```
var listObj = {
   "properties" : {
      "background-color" : "#ccc"
   },
   "children" : [
      {
         "properties" : { "value" : "item-a", "font-size" : "12px", "color" : "red", "h-align" : "left" }
      },
      {
         "properties" : { "value" : "item-b", "font-size" : "12px", "color" : "red", "h-align" : "left" }
      },
      {
         "properties" : { "value" : "item-c", "font-size" : "12px", "color" : "red", "h-align" : "left" }
      }
   ],
   removeItem : function( item ){ /* Logic to remove an item and render the udpated list */ },
   addItem : function( item ){ /* Logic to add an item and render the udpated list */ },
   renderList : function(){ /* Logic to render the udpated list */ }
};
```

Now, notice that `listObj` has only limited number of **properties and methods** to render and manipulate the list.

Only function invocation is required, relatively complex task like rendering the list, removing an item, etc are abstracted.

**Relatively more-complex example**

Similarly, think of a **generic form object** which contains properties to support different kind of controls like label, input boxes, select boxes, etc including *properties specific to each of these different controls* such as a select-box may have source of data (which could be an ajax call).

To represent such properties and methods required to manipulate them, would require more elaborate data-structure, for example

```
var genericFormObj = {
  "name" : "",
  "action" : "",
  "form-attributes" : [
      {
         "order-of-display" : 1, "type" : "label", "value" : "" , "id" : ""
      },
      {
         "order-of-display" : 2, "type" : "textbox", "value" : ""  , "id" : ""
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You are missing out the actual question. How are they represented in memory

Comment: @Shreyas I have elaborated more with examples.