# VirtualDOM of react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm wondering where the virtual dom of react is created.
Hy question is how and where react create the virtual dom and keep a copy of it and me as a react developer how I can gain access to it, any help will be appreciable.

Comment: It's an in-memory representation of the real DOM. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965738/what-is-virtual-dom).

Comment: I understand the concept of virtual dom and why it is created, what i want know is if it is created by react it self or the rendrer and how to get access to it.

Comment: The virtual DOM is created when the render method is called. You can access DOM nodes using `this.refs` or `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(componentInstance)`.

Comment: thats gives access to the real dom not the virtual one