# use plugin International Telephone Input in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm very new to react and I just want to use this https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input plugin in my form. But in the documentation says to use pure js input id query selector to use plugin. But how can I change this kind of code to react usage.

code example in doc:

```
<input type="tel" id="phone">
<script src="path/to/intlTelInput.js"></script>
<script>
  var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
  window.intlTelInput(input);
</script>
```

Comment: check out [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) in react

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings but how to use window.intlTelInput(input) using refs

Comment: The ref will give you the DOM node to call the intlTelInput on. You'll like want to do that call in componentDidMount and/or componentDidUpdate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid to use `Jquery` in `React` projects. You can do it `React` way.

For `intl-tel-input`, there is [react-intl-tel-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intl-tel-input) and [react-intl-tel-input-v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intl-tel-input-v2) packages are available.

```
import ReactIntlTelInput from 'react-intl-tel-input-v2';
import 'intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css';


<ReactIntlTelInput
    value={this.state.value}
    onChange={this.onChange}
/>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dlcprb)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to manipulate the DOM manually since react creates a virtual DOM for performance issues

> React creates a tree of custom objects representing a part of the DOM.
>   For example, instead of creating an actual DIV element containing a UL
>   element, it creates a React.div object that contains a React.ul
>   object. It can manipulate these objects very quickly without actually
>   touching the real DOM or going through the DOM API. Then, when it
>   renders a component, it uses this virtual DOM to figure out what it
>   needs to do with the real DOM to get the two trees to match.
>
> You can think of the virtual DOM like a blueprint. It contains all the
>   details needed to construct the DOM, but because it doesn't require
>   all the heavyweight parts that go into a real DOM, it can be created
>   and changed much more easily.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21965987/6277625)

There's a lot of "ready-made" react components that you can use. You can use [react-phone-number-input](https://github.com/catamphetamine/react-phone-number-input/) for example like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "react-phone-number-input/style.css";
import PhoneInput from "react-phone-number-input";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>International phone number</h1>
      <PhoneInput
        placeholder="Enter phone number"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={inputValue => setInputValue(inputValue)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Take a look at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/laughing-mclean-rngcm)

If you want to learn more about how React manipulates the DOM, you can read [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/dom-manipulation-in-react).

Comment: Thank-you for the answer, react-phone-number-input does the job. Except that it does not auto-detect the location. The original intl tel input has that functionality of geo ip lookup. Do you know any workaround for this ?